# Is there an easy way to show addresses of variables in code::blocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm not so familiar with code::blocks IDE in C programming and I want to watch the addresses of some variables during the debugging process, but I can't find it.

Is there an easy way how I can view addresses of variables during debugging?

Comment: I don't know about code::blocks in particular, but if its debugger can evaluate expressions for you (many debuggers can) then you can probably make it evaluate, even watch, an appropriate address-of expression, *i.e.* `&my_variable`.

Comment: But note that variable's addresses do not change during execution, though this is a bit of a subtle point.  During an object's lifetime, its address is a characteristic property.  The subtlety is in what you consider a "variable".  An identifier with block scope can refer to different objects at different points in a program's execution either because that scope is entered recursively, or because it is exited and then entered again.  I think its easiest to reason about such things by considering such an identifier to represent a different variable each time.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/how-to-examine-variables-with-codeblock-debugger-for-c-programming/

You can see a relevant answer here.